# After updating xCode/Xamarin I get a MT5306 error when building

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

After updating my Xamarin/Xcode I keep getting the following error:
"Failed to create the a fat file. Please review the build log. (MT5306)."

Comment: After struggling for a while I finally found that opening my xCode and accepting the new Terms of Use fixed this for me and I can build my project again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After struggling for a while I finally found that opening my xCode and accepting the new Terms of Use fixed this for me and I can build my project again.

Thought this might save someone out there's time so you don't have to struggle with something that simple like I did.

Comment: FYI: For those users working over a remote shell, you can also `sudo xcodebuild -license` to accept the Xcode/iOS license.