# iOS Simulator not launching after xcode update

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Hi my IOS simulator was working fine with Visual Studio 2017 until recent XCode update and License agreement. I started to run my xamarin app from Visual studio 2017, it showed me error - "xcode license must be accepted in order to be connected". I started my xcode and accepted my licence. iOS simulator 10.3 version got updated to iOS 11. 
When i try to run my application, IOS simulator starts but doesn't launch fully.

I am running my app from Windows machine VS2017- connected mac server agent.
Do i need to do any more update?

Comment: Have you updated VS to the latest VS2017 with Xamarin.iOS 11.0.0.0?

Comment: The answers here should help as its caused by the same issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33362586/after-updating-xcode-xamarin-i-get-a-mt5306-error-when-building/33362653#33362653

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Go to ***Xcode -> Preferences -> Location***
- Check if "Command Line Tool" set
- Run **`sudo xcodebuild -license`** in terminal
- Follow the instructions to accept the license.
- Reopen Visual Studio and you should be able to connect to your Mac without anymore issues!